# C++Builder 10.2 Function-based optimization states "unknown attribute 'optimize' ignored"

Tags: c++, clang, c++builder

I'm trying to set some compiler optimization on a *per-function* function level for a C++Builder 10.2.1 source file and the BCC32c compiler (based on Clang 3.6).

So I have now a function, e.g.

```
std::string __OPTIMIZED ansi(const std::string& str_utf8);
```

where `__OPTIMIZED` is defined as

```
#define __OPTIMIZED __attribute__((optimize("-O3")))
```

which should be a Clang compatible syntax, but BCC32c always states

**[bcc32c Warning] abcdefg.h(256): unknown attribute 'optimize' ignored**

I'm now curious about...

- What would be the right syntax for for optimization on a function level?
- Is such an optimization even possible (and maybe also with the *classic* BCC32), too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++Builder does not support the `optimize` attribute.

The list of supported attributes is available in Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[GNU Attributes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/GNU_Attributes)